# Convert Unix path to windows in QMake Script

Tags: windows, qt, path, qmake, visual-studio-2010

Is there anyway to get the windows style path to the directory containing the `.pro` or convert what is stored in `_PRO_FILE_PWD_` to a Windows style path ?

---

I have an issue with the `_PRO_FILE_PWD_` variable in Qmake where it returns a unix style path on windows.

e.g `c:/foo/bar` instead of `c:\foo\bar`

This is proving a problem where the path is being used as part of a post link step.

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy /y $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\\QtCore4.dll  $${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/bin/;
```

I use the `.pro` file to create a Visual Studio project and I can see that if I manually change the forward slashes to back slashes in VS that everything is copied fine without any errors.

I get the following error in Visual Studio if I don't correct the path.

```
PostBuildEvent:
1>  Description: copy /y C:\Qt\4.8.3\bin\QtCore4.dll E:/foo/build/win32//bin//;
1>  The syntax of the command is incorrect.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: The command "copy /y C:\Qt\4.8.3\bin\QtCore4.dll E:/foo/build/win32/bin/;
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1.
```

---

**Solution**

Very simple solution thanks to Roku by adding escaped double quotes around the path using / characters.

```
MAKE_POST_LINK += 
    copy /y $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\\QtCore4.dll \"$${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/bin/\";
```

Note for addingi multiple copy commands you must seperate them with the ampersand the semicolon doesn't work.

e.g.

```
 MAKE_POST_LINK += 
        copy /y $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\\QtCore4.dll \"$${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/bin/\" &
    MAKE_POST_LINK += 
        copy /y $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\\QtGui4.dll \"$${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/bin/\";
```

Comment: Are you sure the character / is the problem? It works almost everywhere in Windows. Have you copy-pasted the copy line to command prompt and tried it there? Could the last ; be the problem?

Comment: @Roku I just tried on the command prompt.. It doesn't work with / only \. The ; is there because I have a few copy commands.. I have tried without...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this working by adding escaped double quotes around the path using / characters:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += 
    copy /y $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]\\QtCore4.dll \"$${_PRO_FILE_PWD_}/bin/\";
```

Comment: Thanks Roku for finding a very simple solution! Note the semicolon doesn't work for separating multiple commands -I had to use the ampersand.

Comment: This solution is not crossplateform: you should prefer @edwinc answer using $$shell_path()

Comment: It also doesn't work when the source path uses forward slashes. Added a workaround for Qt4

Answer (score 14):

`$$shell_path()` will convert the slashes to local system format, so:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += copy /y "$$shell_path($$QT_INSTALL_BINS/QtCore4.dll)" "$$shell_path($$_PROD_FILE_PWD_/bin)"
```

Comment: worked for me on win 8 / Qt 5.4 Thanks! You could also call `$$QMAKE_COPY` instead of `copy /y` this is replaced with a platform independent version of copy.

Answer (score 6):

Oddly enough, escaping the double quotes works for the destination file but not the source.

i.e. this works:

```
copy C:\dev\playground\qt\SampleProject\debug_qt.conf "C:/dev/playground/qt/build-SampleProject-Qt_8_4_6_Desktop-Debug/qt.conf"
```

but this doesn't:

```
copy "C:/dev/playground/qt/SampleProject/debug_qt.conf" "C:/dev/playground/qt/build-SampleProject-Qt_8_4_6_Desktop-Debug/qt.conf"
```

As already noted, [`$$shell_path(path)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-function-reference.html#shell-path-path) works under Qt5.

On Qt4, [`$$replace(string, old_string, new_string)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-function-reference.html#replace-string-old-string-new-string) can be used instead.

Example:

```
MY_PATH = $$PWD
message($$replace(MY_PATH, /, \\))
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for putting both qt4 and qt5 solutions there.